# Diferença entre usar um Stream ou Collection

Tags: java, desempenho, java-8, stream

Vejo que o uso de *stream* do Java 8 é recomendado para grande quantidade de dados. Se o conjunto  de dados é pequeno, há algum ganho em relação ao uso somente de `Collection`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O *stream* não foi criado para melhorar algo de acordo com a quantidade dados. Ele existe para dar mais expressividade, e supostamente legibilidade. Então seu código deve ficar mais claro, e simples indicando o que você quer sem se preocupar com o como fazer. É uma forma de tornar a linguagem mais declarativa e menos imperativa.

Se estiver pensando em performance então o *stream* é ruim, especialmente com grandes volumes, até porque com pequenos toda performance é aceitável.

Comment: Digamos que eu não queira processar todo esse volume de dados como uma Collection

Comment: Novamente, o *stream* não foi criado pra isso, você consegue fazer igual sem *stream*, só será mais verboso e correrá mais risco, não importa a quantidade de dados, ou se ele será parcial ou não. O *stream* não foi criado para processar algo parcial, isso é algo de alguns algoritmos específicos que já criaram no *stream*, vários deles sequer é possível executar parcialmente.

Comment: Maniero qual é o algoritmo de ordenação utilizado nas streams?

Comment: @ayowoleagbedejobi não sei sobre o que está falando, está sem contexto.

Comment: @Maniero No caso eu uso o método de ordenação chamado 'sorted' na Stream, só que não sei o algoritmo de ordenação que é utilizado ao invocar esse método e se é um algoritmo eficiênte.

Comment: Se essa minha dúvida fugir do escopo dessa pergunta me informe que eu crio uma outra pergunta.

Comment: @ayowoleagbedejobi Ok, você usam um método entre eles que faz classificação da coleção. Não sei dizer qual é, até porque deve ser um detalhe de implementação, mas o assunto aqui não é sobre isto, pode fazer uma pergunta e quem souber poderá responder.